# Random Never same 12 digits code Python

Tags: python

I have a python script which is the follow

```
def id_generator(size=12, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
```

how do I do that to generate it till it fullfills all possibilities without outputting the same thing twice?
I need 12 random characters of a-z/0-9 and need to fullfill all the possibilities. Thanks

Comment: What could you do with the billions of results this will give?

Comment: Use `random.shuffle` and iterate through the first `size` elements?

Comment: if you want to have all possible outcomes, why not just list them, like start with `aaaaaaaaaaa`, then `aaaaaaaaaab` .... `aaaaaaaaaa9`, `aaaaaaaaaba` ...?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need, but take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: Could you please define or rephrase "fullfills all possibilities"

Comment: 1./ why use random if you want all possible cases generated? there is a possibility for it NEVER to happen. 2./ all possibilities that means 36 ^ 12 which is 4738381338321616896 ...

Comment: I think the OP means to output a string of `size` characters, where each character *inside* the string is unique, not repeated. Not all possibilities of `size`-length strings.

Comment: @roganjosh: My bad, I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: @TheNavigat no harm done, I was just genuinely confused by your points :)

Answer (score 1):

if you are expecting all the permutations of the 12 digit string, give this a shot

```
def id_generator(size=12, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

from itertools import permutations
perms = [''.join(p) for p in permutations(id_generator())]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to output a string of size characters, where each character inside the string is unique (thus not repeated), you can use this:

```
import random
import string

def id_generator(size=12, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    chars = list(chars)
    random.shuffle(chars)
    return ''.join(chars[:size])
```